# OneNote alternative for Windows, Linux, and Android

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, android, note-taking

I’m looking for an alternative to Microsoft OneNote. I usually use OneNote to sync my notes between my Windows 8 computer and my Android phone, but I’ve been using Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) quite often lately, and I want to be able to have a program to sync my notes.

I want it to have the following:

- Able to easily sync with an account, so I can see my notes on any device
- Has programs/apps for Linux, Windows 8, and Android (I don’t want to have to go in a browser to see them)
- Able to view/edit notes offline, and syncs once connected to Internet again
- Support for check-lists, pictures, and links
- Free

I know that OneNote has a web app, accessible through most browsers, but I want a program. I don't want to have to open a browser to see my notes. That would also make it so I *had* to be online to use it, and I’m not always able to access the Internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have always used [Evernote](http://evernote.com/evernote/) for note taking in class. I used it very heavily, without internet, for a long time without problems.

> Evernote makes it easy to remember things big and small from your everyday life using your computer, phone, tablet and the web.

It offers a great UI and an even better back-end (syncing and such). The only downside to Evernote is that you have a monthly limit (100MB) for how much you can sync, but if you are just taking notes (text notes), you are never going to reach that limit. So rather than a storage limit you have to adherer to, you just have to watch that you don't go over 100MB per month, other than its unlimited storage.

Features:

- Very easily syncs with one account to all devices
- Has an offical app for Windows and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote) but no *official* one for Linux. There are community created clients, such as [Everpad](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad),  [Nevernote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/) or [Geeknote](http://www.geeknote.me/) (this one supports OS X as well)
- Able to view and edit notes offline while waiting for a connection (used this feature many o' times)
- Not sure about the checklist feature but you can create bullet points and put strike through text when you are done with them. Supports pictures and links
- Free (ad supported) with the option of getting [premium](http://evernote.com/premium/)
- Ability to create different note books and tags for organizational purposes
- Ability to add audio clips to notes as well as pictures and other files of your choice
- Every feature you would expect in a basic word processor (fonts, colours, formatting etc)
- Ability to "email in" a note to yourself so that if for some reason you can't access your Evernote, you can just send an email to it and it'll be there waiting for you when you get back
- Ability to take a snapshot of a webpage and save it to your notebook]
- Collaboration features

I know you talk about not wanting to use a web app but I have to mention it. Evernote has such a great web app I have never used anything in my life that is more simple as what they have created. Its so easy to use and won't cause you any hassle, ever. It is perfect if you are away from your computer/mobile device and have to access Evernote. It won't take two seconds to load up and get the information you need.

Comment: I would second this - especially the web app side. I ditched any desktop versions and just run Evernote in Chrome or Web (Epiphany) web app mode..

Comment: http://www.nixnote.org/. Nixnote2 is the best Evernote client for Linux and I have tried multiple others.

Answer (score 1):

I use [google keep](https://keep.google.com/)

Best feature it syncs notes with your google account. available for windows/linux and mobile also.

It has notes, check list and remainders also.

since it's from google remainders are synced to your calendar also

Go ahead and try it.